# How do I prove that the area of any triangle can be obtained using "Heron’s Formula" $\longrightarrow A_t = \sqrt{s(s - a)(s - b)(s - c)}$?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, area

My brother was told to find the area of a right-angled triangle. He knew that if he made a copy of the right-angle triangle so that there were two, joining the longest side of each triangle together, he would form a square or a rectangle. Because of this he knew that the area of the right-angled triangle was half the area of the square/rectangle.

Let:

$p = \text{area of right-angled triangle;}$

$q = \text{area of rectangle;}$

$l = \text{length of the rectangle; and}$

$w = \text{height (altitude) of the rectangle.}$

Given this information, my brother was able to find out that:
$$p = \left\{\frac{q}{2} : q = lw\right\}$$

He then asked me, why the area of *any* triangle uses the same formula, because you can't always make two copies of a triangle, join the longest sides together, and then make a square/rectangle. It sometimes makes a parallelogram depending on your triangle!

I replied that for *any* four-sided shape, the area will always equal its length multiplied by its width. It does not have to be a *square* or *rectangle* in order for it to work. The formula for finding the area of a square is the same for a rectangle, but is also the same for a diamond and the same for a parallelogram as well.

Then my brother said to me that because the same formula applied to *all* four-sided shapes, he did not have to join two copies of the triangle together. He drew an equilateral triangle $\triangle$ and then fitted a square over it $\square$ such that the bottom length of the square was the base of the triangle.
[image]
Then my brother said to me;

> **"If we label the sides of the square $x$ since they are equal to each other, and the area of the triangle $y$, how can you prove that $y = \frac{x^2}{2}$?"**

Well, I know that the two blue seperate areas inside the square are not covered by the triangle, thus if we add them together, they will equal the area of the triangle. Let's call these particular areas $z_1$ and $z_2$. Both $z_1$ and $z_2$ are *also* triangles, so for some value $a$ and some value $b$, $\frac{ab}{2}$ is equal to the area of $z_1$ and $z_2$, such that $a$ is equal to each long side length of $z_1$ and $z_2$, and $b$ is equal to each short side length of $z_1$ and $z_2$. (Here we exclude the longest side of the triangles, since each triangle has *three* sides but we are only including two in this case.)

I knew that I could use the same method my brother used of finding the value of $p$ (the area of the right-angled triangle he was looking for), meaning that I could actually split the square in half so it is combined with two rectangles $r_1$ and $r_2$, drawing a line straight down from the top corner of the triangle across its centre. The width of $r_1$ is $m$ and the width of $r_2$ is $n$.

I know that:
$$m + n = \left\{x : x = \text{length of the square, namely the length of the base of the triangle}\right\}$$
And I also know that:
$$y = z_1 + z_2 = \frac{mx}{2} + \frac{nx}{2} = \frac{mx + nx}{2} = \left\{\frac{x(m + n)}{2} : y = \text{area of triangle}\right\}$$
And since we already clarified that $m + n = x$, this proves that $y = \frac{x^2}{2}$ and thus if we covered a rectangle or parallelogram etc over the triangle instead, labelling the length $l$ and the width $w$, the area of the triangle would equal $\frac{lw}{2}$.

I was actually very proud that I had done this, because it took me about $15$-$20$ minutes to prove this, and I showed my science teacher to see if I had done it correctly. (I didn't have maths, but I did have science and my science teacher is fairly good at maths. Note, this is yesterday I am talking about.) He said that I did it correctly, but now he has another challenge for me (assuming that I have spare time to complete it after I did the science homework, which I do), however, when I was doing the challenge last night, I didn't know where to begin:

> **Challenge**:
>
> Prove that the area of any triangle can be obtained using *Heron's Fomula*: $$\begin{align} A_t = \sqrt{s(s - a)(s - b)(s - c)} \ : A_t &= \text{Area of triangle} \\
> s &= \frac{a + b + c}{2} \\
> (a, b, c) &= \text{Side lengths of triangle}
> \end{align}$$
>
> **Extra:**
>   If you have an equilateral triangle with a side-length $x$, drawing a line $y$ from the top corner down across the centre, how long would $y$ be such that $(x, y)\in \mathbb{R}$?

For the *Extra* part, according to the given information, $y$ must include $x$, and according to the Pythagorean Theorem $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$, I may be able to find $y$.

Since we are splitting the equilateral triangle in half, we would have two right-angled triangles, where their longest side is $x$, their second longest side is $y$, and their shortest side is of course $\frac{x}{2}$.

$$\begin{align}
\therefore y &= \sqrt{x - \bigg(\frac{x}{2}\bigg)^2} \\
&= \sqrt{x - \bigg(\frac{x^2}{2^2}\bigg)} \\
&= \sqrt{x - \bigg(\frac{x^2}{4}\bigg)} \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{4x - x^2}{4}} \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{x(4 - x)}{4}} \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{x(4 - x)}}{2} \\
\end{align}$$
But:
$$(x, y)\in \mathbb{R} \implies x\in \mathbb{R} \implies x \leqslant 4 \ \lor \ x \geqslant 4$$
And:
$$y\in \mathbb{C}\notin \mathbb{R} \iff x > 4$$
So this becomes a problem, and for the part concerning *Heron's Formula*, I am not familiar with it and only heard about it when my science teacher told me about it. Could you please help me with this and show me what to do? I would appreciate it if you gave me an example of how this formula works and how this *Heron* person discovered it. (And trust me, I won't steal all the credit when I show my science teacher the proof.)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://galileoandeinstein.physics.virginia.edu/more_stuff/Heron.html

Comment: @Khosrotash thank you! I also found another link here: $$\longrightarrow \text{http://www.se16.info/hgb/triangle.htm}$$ and here: $$\longrightarrow \text{https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576831/proof-of-herons-formula-for-the-area-of-a-triangle?rq=1}$$ explaining the proof. But none of the links explain where I went wrong for the *Extra* part.

Comment: Whoops something happened to the comment and I can't fix it up because it's too late, but I'm sure you know what I mean

Comment: In your extra part you forgot to square $x$. $y=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x$

Comment: So $$y = \frac{x\sqrt{3}}{2}$$ Ok thanks for that :)

Comment: The triangle in the picture is not equilateral or the quadrilateral is not a square. Indeed if the triangle was equilateral we had an isosceles triangle (the triangle to the left which has a side equal to the square's side and a side equal to central triangle's side) with two right angles which is impossible. An equilateral traingle in a square looks like this https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/PaperFolding/EquilateralTriangleInSquareS1.jpg

Comment: @Raffaele ooohhh good point! But I still believe the user who uploaded the post did an excellent job of proving how $A_t = \frac{1}{2}bh$

Comment: @Raffaele yes u’re right. Say if the base of the triangle was $1$ unit, then the length of one side of the square would also be $1$ unit, making the other two sides of the triangle a quarter units longer, and thus not equilateral. Thanks for that :)

Comment: A geometric proof using incircle and excircle is presented at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3752471/72968 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3495553/72968

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Since
$$
\begin{align}
a^2&=c_a^2+h^2\\
b^2&=c_b^2+h^2
\end{align}
$$
we get
$$
\begin{align}
c_a+c_b&=c\\
c_a-c_b&=\frac{a^2-b^2}c
\end{align}
$$
therefore,
$$
c_a=\frac{a^2-b^2+c^2}{2c}
$$
The square of the area is
$$
\begin{align}
A^2
&=\frac14c^2h^2\\
&=\frac14c^2\left(a^2-c_a^2\right)\\
&=\frac14c^2\left(a-c_a\right)\left(a+c_a\right)\\
&=\frac14c^2\left(a-\frac{a^2-b^2+c^2}{2c}\right)\left(a+\frac{a^2-b^2+c^2}{2c}\right)\\
&=\frac1{16}\left(2ac-a^2-c^2+b^2\right)\left(2ac+a^2+c^2-b^2\right)\\[3pt]
&=\frac1{16}\left(b^2-(a-c)^2\right)\left((a+c)^2-b^2\right)\\[3pt]
&=\frac{(b-a+c)(b+a-c)(a+c-b)(a+c+b)}{16}\\[6pt]
&=(s-a)(s-c)(s-b)s
\end{align}
$$

Comment: This is actually a much better answer than Michael’s, purely because of the picture even though I understand anyway. Thank you very much nonetheless! $$(+1) \ \ \color{green}{\checkmark}$$

Comment: This is a special case of [Brahmagupta's Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta_theorem) of which I provide a proof in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1254192).

Comment: I think you should put more explanation on those steps. for example, why ca-cb is (a^2-b^2)/c. I know why. You factor a^2-b^2 factorization. But most won't. Also how do you get good mathtex editor?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

This is from an article I remember reading in an AMS journal.

Let $D$ be the point of intersection of the internal bisectors of $\angle A$, $\angle B$, and $\angle C$. Let $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ be the measures of the corresponding bisected angles. Note 
$$\alpha + \beta + \gamma = \frac 12 \pi.$$
Let $r$ be the common distance from the point $D$ to the sides 
$\overline{AB}$, $\overline{BC}$, and $\overline{CA}$. Define
$$s = \frac 12(a+b+c).$$
Note that the feet of the perpendiculars drawn from point $D$ to the sides $\overline{AB}$, $\overline{BC}$, and $\overline{CA}$ create segments with the indicated lengths. Let $u,v,$ and $w$ be the respective lengths of the segments drawn from point $D$ to points $A$, $B$, and $C$. Then

\begin{align}
   (s-a)+ir = ue^{i \alpha}\\
   (s-b)+ir = ve^{i \beta}\\
   (s-c)+ir = we^{i \gamma}\\
\end{align}

So $(s-a+ir)(s-b+ir)(s-c+ir)=uvwe^{\frac 12 i\pi}=iuvw$. Hence the real part of
$(s-a+ir)(s-b+ir)(s-c+ir)$ is equal to $0$.

We compute
\begin{align}
   \Re[(s-a+ir)(s-b+ir)(s-c+ir)] &= 0 \\
   (s-a)(s-b)(s-c)-r^2[(s-a)+(s-b)+(s-c)] &= 0 \\
   sr^2 &= (s-a)(s-b)(s-c) \\
   r &= \sqrt{\frac{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}{s}}
\end{align}

Hence the area of $\triangle ABC$ is

$$ \frac 12r(a+b+c) = rs = \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)} $$

Comment: I understand everything apart from the second half, but that is ok. I acknowledge the effort you put into formatting this post. $(+1)$

Comment: Dude what the hell is point P? You mean point D?

Comment: @J.Chang - Thanks. I fixed it.

Comment: Very great. Why does distance between a and the r are (s-a). I didn't get that part. Looks correct. But why?

Comment: @J.Chang - The angle bisectors and the perpendiculars form congruent right triangles. The rest is just algebra.

Comment: The algebra is simple. I just notice that x,y,z (the distance between A and the circle), are simply s. Namely 2(x+y+z) is simply the circumference of the triangle. I would add this to make things more clear. By the way, turning into complex plan is kind of a trick isn't it? Is it a common trick?

Comment: @J.Chang - Not that I know of. I would love to see other proofs where complex numbers show up out of nowhere and turn out to be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Let $AB=c$, $AC=b$, $BC=a$, $a=\max\{a,b,c\}$ and $AD$ be an altitude of $\Delta ABC$.

Thus, $D$ placed between $B$ and $C$.

Hence, by the Pythagoras's theorem 
$$AH^2=c^2-BD^2=b^2-(a-BD)^2.$$

Thus, $$c^2-BD^2=b^2-a^2+2aBD-BD^2,$$ 
which gives $$BD=\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2a}$$ and from here
$$AD=\sqrt{c^2-BD^2}=\sqrt{c^2-\left(\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2a}\right)^2}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2a}\sqrt{4a^2c^2-(a^2+c^2-b^2)^2}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2a}\sqrt{2ac-a^2-c^2+b^2)(2ac+a^2+c^2-b^2)}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2a}\sqrt{(b^2-(a-c)^2)((a+c)^2-b^2)}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2a}\sqrt{(a+b-c)(b+c-a)(a+b+c)(a+c-b)}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2a}\sqrt{(a+b+c-2c)(b+c+a-2a)(a+b+c)(a+c+b-2b)}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2a}\sqrt{(2s-2c)(2s-2a)(2s)(2s-2b)}=$$
$$=\frac{2}{a}\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}.$$
Id est,
$$S_{\Delta ABC}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot a\cdot\frac{2}{a}\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}=$$
$$=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}.$$
and we are done!

Comment: I did not know what max{${a, b, c}$} meant but I did a little bit of research and correct me if I am wrong, but I think if this equals $a$ then that implies that $a > b\land c$. The rest, I understand :) Thank you so much!! You actually gave a better explanation in your answer than the links provided! $$(+1) \ \ \checkmark$$ and we are done!

Comment: @user477343 I want that $D$ will be between $B$ and $C$ for which we can assume that $a\geq b$ and $a\geq c$. We can assume this think because there is a symmetry in our reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

In my [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4379259/732917), I had shown that
$$
r^{2}(x+y+z)=x y z \tag*{(result 1)} 
$$
and
$$
K=r s \tag*{(result 3)} 
$$
where $s=x+y+z$ is the semi-perimeter of the triangle ABC whose area is $K$   and sides $a=y+z, b=z+x $ and $c=x+y$.

From (1), $r^{2} s=x y z$ implies that
$$
K^{2}=r^2s^2 =sxy z=s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)
$$

Taking square root on both sides yields the Heron’s Formula
$$
K=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}
$$

Comment: (+1) This is beautifully concise: far less algebra than most proofs of Heron's formula! An equivalent method: use the trigonometric identity $\cot \alpha + \cot \beta + \cot \gamma = \cot \alpha \cot \beta \cot \gamma$ when $\alpha + \beta + \gamma$ makes a right angle. Since $x = s-a = r \cot \alpha$ etc, $s = x + y + z = r(\cot \alpha + \cot \beta + \cot \gamma)$ so $s = r(\cot \alpha \cot \beta \cot \gamma) = xyz/r^2$ and $K^2 = r^2s^2=sxyz$. But proof of that trig identity is equivalent to your result 1 and can be deduced from [your diagram](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4379259/732917)